# Right click doesn't work in plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am following this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html#exercise-adding-e4view-based-parts-to-3-x-based-applications . When I'm trying to right click in extension tab to add a new e4View as shown in a tutorial, nothing happens, the popup menu doesn't appear. Is it possible to create this view in different way?

[image: my plugin.xml]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always edit the plugin.xml directly by clicking on the 'plugin.xml' tab.

A basic e4view would look something like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
  <e4view
        class="testview.E4view1"
        id="TestView.e4view1"
        name="name"
        restorable="true">
  </e4view>
</extension>
```